# Mongo how to filter by unordered nested fields

Tags: mongodb

I have following document in a collection in a MongoDB database:

```
 {
    _id: 'anID',
    data: { field1: 100, field2: 'str' }
 }
```

Following code is able to find and update the document:

```
filter := bson.M{
        "_id": "anID",
        "data": bson.M{
            "field1": 100,
            "field2": "str",
        },
    }

    newData := bson.M{
        "field1": 200,
        "field2": "str2",
    }

    update := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"data": nextData}}

    res, err := collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)
```

If I change the `filter` to following, the code is no longer able to find and update the document:

```
filter := bson.M{
        "_id": "anID",
        "data": bson.M{
            "field2": "str",
            "field1": 100,
        },
    }
```

How can I filter without depending on the order of fields in nested documents? Is using dot notation the only way to do this in a foolproof manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 filter := bson.M{
         "_id": "anID",
         "data.field1": 100,
         "data.field2": "str"
         }
     }
```